# Selectively interating through an multidimentional associative array by their indexes in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I m developing a website using php and I am fetching the data from sql server. What I need to do is there are 2 rows which will contain 3 columns of data each. The associative array I store the data has 6 sub-arrays. I need to create a loop where after 3 entries, a new row is created and the data of next three in printed in next row.

I tried using while loop but I dont know how I can separate the array by their indexes as doing while($index = mysqli_fetch_assoc(r)) will print all the data but I want 3 to be in one row and 3 in the next. Thanks!

```
        <?php
        $q = "SELECT * FROM main_intro";
        $r = mysqli_query($link, $q) or die(mysqli_error($link));
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($r);
        $count = 0;
        $intro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
        $keys = array_keys($intro) ?>

        <div class="row custom_pad">
            <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2><?php echo $intro['image']; ?><?php echo $intro['heading']; ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $intro['data']; ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php} ?>
            <!-- -->
        </div>
```

What I need is, in first row, i need the first 3 array data and then in next row, i need the other 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a condition in the loop and check for `$iterator%3==0` , if condition matches increment the array index

For example

```
$arr = [];
$j=0;
for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++){
  $arr[$j][] = $i;
  if($i%3==0) $j++;  
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 9
    )

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to populate three columns of each row with appropriate data. Right now you are fetching just one row from the result set, you have to use `while` loop to loop through the result set and appropriately fill each column using *that* `for` loop.

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT * FROM main_intro";
$r = mysqli_query($link, $q) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while($intro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
    ?>
    <div class="row custom_pad">
        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php
                    switch($i){
                        case 0:
                            echo $intro['image'];
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            echo '<h2>' . $intro['heading'] . '</h2>';
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            echo '<p>' . $intro['data'] . '</p>';
                            break;
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php 
        } 
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```